# How to use <Trans /> of react-i18next for an alt image translation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation, jsx, i18next

I've an issue that should be (hopefully) simple to solve.
I've installed `react-i18next` in my project and all works fine, I am able to have translations in Functional components, in classes, but my only issue now is in a class component, specifically regarding an html attribute, I'm talking about the alt of an image.

```
// ...
import { Translation, Trans } from 'react-i18next'

class MyComponent extends Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
  constructor(props: MyComponentProps) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isButtonVisible: true,
      isAnimationVisible: false,
      deadline: 0,
      countdown: ''
    }

    // ...
  }

  // ...

  render () {
    const { isButtonVisible, isAnimationVisible, deadline } = this.state

    return (
      <>
        <Trans>
          <img className={styles.exercise} src={lungs} alt={`${t('animation.lungs')} IDXXX`}  />
        </Trans>
      <>
    )
  }
}
```

where `animation.lungs` is my translations in locales file and IDXXX is a numeric id that does not require any translation.

The t is not defined and it makes sense, but documentation here is not clear https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/trans-component for me. 
Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is `t` not defined? In which context is the `img` tag?

Comment: hey @SagiRika I updated the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the `withTranslation` HOC in order to get access to `t()`.

```
import { Translation, Trans, withTranslation, WithTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

type MyComponentProps = {} & WithTranslation

class MyComponent extends Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
  constructor(props: MyComponentProps) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isButtonVisible: true,
      isAnimationVisible: false,
      deadline: 0,
      countdown: ''
    }

    // ...
  }

  // ...

  render () {
    const { isButtonVisible, isAnimationVisible, deadline } = this.state
    const { t } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <Trans>
          <img className={styles.exercise} src={lungs} alt={`${t('animation.lungs')} IDXXX`}  />
        </Trans>
      <>
    )
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(MyComponent)
```

Comment: I reviewed and fixed your answer, now it works, thanks

Comment: Or, `<img className={styles.exercise} src={lungs} alt={t('animation.lungs') + 'IDXXX'}  />`